# Rust constant expression depends on a generic parameter

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to generalize some algebraic operations in Rust (like for groups, rings, fields, etc), and I ran into this problem trying to implement the cross product of two "sets" (Vec's).

(Note that this is using `const_generics` in the nightly toolchain.)

```
fn CrossProduct<T, const N: usize, const M: usize>(lhs: Vec<[T;N]>, rhs: Vec<[T;M]>) -> Vec<[T;N+M]> {
    let mut out: Vec<[T;N+M]> = Vec::with_capacity(lhs.len() * rhs.len());

    for i in 0..lhs.len() {
        for j in 0..rhs.len() {
            let mut inner: [T; N+M] = [lhs[i][0]; N+M];
            for idx in 1..N {
                inner[idx] = lhs[i][idx];
            }
            for idx in 0..M {
                inner[idx + N] = rhs[j][idx];
            }
            out.push(inner);
        }
    }
    out
}
```

Wherever I have the expression `[T;N+M]`, I get an error that says **constant expression depends on a generic parameter**, which makes no sense.

Comment: At first glance, I'd guess that this is just not implemented yet. Const generics are far from complete. You may want to search for a GitHub issue on rust-lang/rust to see the status of expressions like this.

Answer (score 5):

Your code does actually [compile on the latest nightly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4e145a72a5db1dc3759b1d39dc2515a), all you need is a couple of feature flags.

```rust
#![feature(const_generics)]
#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked)]
fn CrossProduct<T: Copy, const N: usize, const M: usize>(lhs: Vec<[T;N]>, rhs: Vec<[T;M]>) -> Vec<[T;N+M]> {
    let mut out: Vec<[T;N+M]> = Vec::with_capacity(lhs.len() * rhs.len());

    for i in 0..lhs.len() {
        for j in 0..rhs.len() {
            let mut inner: [T; N+M] = [lhs[i][0]; N+M];
            for idx in 1..N {
                inner[idx] = lhs[i][idx];
            }
            for idx in 0..M {
                inner[idx + N] = rhs[j][idx];
            }
            out.push(inner);
        }
    }
    out
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![[1i32,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
    let b = vec![[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
    println!("{:?}", CrossProduct(a, b));
}
```

And when trying to compile with just `#![feature(min_const_generics)]`, compiler actually recommends this solution:

```
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> src/main.rs:2:102
  |
2 | fn CrossProduct<T: Copy, const N: usize, const M: usize>(lhs: Vec<[T;N]>, rhs: Vec<[T;M]>) -> Vec<[T;N+M]> {
  |                                                                                                      ^ cannot perform const operation using `N`
  |
  = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `N`
  = help: use `#![feature(const_generics)]` and `#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked)]` to allow generic const expressions
```

Comment: Beware that both of these features are still incomplete, so even though you can use them, they may bring with them compiler bugs that cause your programs to misbehave (as the compiler warns about). You should definitely not be using these features for any production code yet.

Comment: Looks like these features have been removed in favour of `generic_const_exprs`