# associated type `Element` not found for `Self`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to wrap `to_be_bytes` method into traits(currently they are implement directly from primitive types), so that I can use it on generic types. Here's my code:

```
trait ToBeBytes {
    fn to_be_bytes(&self) -> [u8; mem::size_of::<Self>()];
}
```

the problem occurs at `mem::size_of::<Self>()`, the compiler said that

> the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time

I came up with a concept called type placeholder, so I changed to this:

```
trait ToBeBytes {
    type Element;
    fn to_be_bytes(&self) -> [u8; mem::size_of::<Self::Element>()];
}
```

and now the compiler said:

> associated type `Element` not found for `Self`

I tried the example in tutorials:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    type Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

and it compiles.

So what's the difference between my code and the example? How can I accomplish my goal (wrap `to_be_bytes` into traits)?

Comment: This compiles for me but requires feature flags (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461672/rust-constant-expression-depends-on-a-generic-parameter; note the comment there and the warnings produced by the compiler): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fcd1fb57409122e8eba05ed0c43b23c5

Comment: Your original design can be fixed but requires the same feature flags: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a162f3965efae40417743750f201321a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling your code results in the following error:

```
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> src/lib.rs:4:55
  |
4 |     fn to_be_bytes(&self) -> [u8; std::mem::size_of::<Self>()];
  |                                                       ^^^^ cannot perform const operation using `Self`
  |
  = note: type parameters may not be used in const expressions
  = help: use `#![feature(const_generics)]` and `#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked)]` to allow generic const expressions
```

And sure enough, your code compiles with `#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked, const_generics)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that rust do not fully support constant generic yet, according to this [blog](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/02/26/const-generics-mvp-beta.html):

> Currently, const parameters may only be instantiated by const
> arguments of the following forms:
>
> - A standalone const parameter.
> - A literal (i.e. an integer, bool, or
>   character).
> - A concrete constant expression (enclosed by {}), involving
>   no generic parameters.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> fn foo<const N: usize>() {}
>
> fn bar<T, const M: usize>() {
>     foo::<M>(); // ok: `M` is a const parameter
>     foo::<2021>(); // ok: `2021` is a literal
>     foo::<{20 * 100 + 20 * 10 + 1}>(); // ok: const expression contains no generic parameters
>     
>     foo::<{ M + 1 }>(); // error: const expression contains the generic parameter `M`
>     foo::<{ std::mem::size_of::<T>() }>(); // error: const expression contains the generic parameter `T`
>     
>     let _: [u8; M]; // ok: `M` is a const parameter
>     let _: [u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()]; // error: const expression contains the generic parameter `T` 
> }
> ```