# create a matrix with constant generic like a vector

Tags: rust

I would like to create the following matrix:

- the internal structure is a 1 dimensional array.
- I want the dimentions to be known at the compilation time.

```
pub struct Matrix<LikeNumber,const len: usize, const width : usize>{
      elements : [LikeNumber;width*len]
}
```

but I have the following problem

> elements : [LikeNumber;width*len]
> |                            ^^^^^ cannot perform const operation using `width`
> |
> = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `width`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust constant expression depends on a generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461672/rust-constant-expression-depends-on-a-generic-parameter)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, this is just not yet supported by Rust. You can only use generic const parameters on their own, and not as part of a constant expression.

If you compile this on the Nightly compiler, you get this error message:

```
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> src/lib.rs:3:30
  |
3 |       elements : [LikeNumber;width*len]
  |                              ^^^^^ cannot perform const operation using `width`
  |
  = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `width`
  = help: use `#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]` to allow generic const expressions
```

Enabling `#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]` in your code enables support for this on the Nightly compiler. You currently need to add a dummy bound to make the code compile, though:

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub struct Matrix<T, const LEN: usize, const WIDTH: usize>
where
    [T; WIDTH * LEN]:,
{
    elements: [T; WIDTH * LEN],
}
```

The bound basically asserts that the expression is "evaluatable". A dedicated syntax for this is planned before this feature becomes available in stable Rust.

Note that the `generic_const_exprs` is still incomplete, and has a lot of subtle bugs.